# Benefits of Diversification and Rebalancing with negatively skewed leptokurtic return distribution?

Tags: portfolio, diversification, skewness, rebalancing, kurtosis

I am missing tools to investigate this issue. I am trying to solve this question [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/1356/956). What kind of issues should you acknowledge over the naive diversification/rebalancing with normal distribution? You could have a different return distribution curve so does the distribution affect the benefits? If you know how to investigate this kind of problem, please, let me know -- I am unsure whether this runs over the properties of mean-variance portfolio optimization (MVO).

Comment: ...btw from simple time-serie standpoint, autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation decay pretty fast (after sufficient diversification etc) -- how to account this kind of thing? As far as I have understood, the financial time-series are not really naive realization of certain theoretical models such as SARIMA, rather dynamic (even a bit artistic) and my feeling is that to really "solve" this kind of problems would require quite amount of research, well there must be some papers on this -- investigating.